# How do I configure my Apache web server to respond only to requests made to it's domain name and not the IP address?

Tags: webserver, apache-http-server

I would like my server to not serve the home page when it is accessed by its IP address.

This is to prevent worms from spidering the site. Worms randomly scan for IP addresses and they might spot the site. If the site only responds to domain names, then most worms that just scan for IP addresses will not reach the site.

How could a web server be configured to respond only to the requests made to the domain name and not the IP address?

Comment: @Begueradj: Isn't *web app hardening* part of the [on-topic subjects](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of this site?

Comment: what if you add a virtualhost to the ip and another to the actual domain?

Comment: @Begueradj: catch-all domains are a common security features included in web server configurations, and after a quick check I did not see it currently mentioned anywhere on Security.SE, so it could be a good occasion for this :). However, this common feature being not specific to a certain web server, I agree there is no point discussion the actual implementation for each and every web server available here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define what is called a *catch-all* domain.

The exact configuration depends on the web server type and version you use, for instance on Apache 2 it will go through the definition of a [`_default_`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default) vhost.

The idea though remains always the same:

- You define several virtual hosts (or the equivalent depending on your web server software) matching each one a domain you handle,
- You define one catch-all virtual host which will match any other domain and will ensure the default behavior for your server (reject the connection, redirect to a proper default URL, etc.).

Once you know the name, "*catch-all domain*", you should have no difficulties to check your web server documentation or online How-to's to learn how to implement this feature in your own environment.

Answer (score 1):

[ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org) can do it for you. It's a web application firewall that runs as Apache/IIS/Nginx module. DigitalOcian has written a simple [Getting Started Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu) for Debian/Ubuntu. But depending on your distribution the package names may be different. For example, on the CentOS-based Amazon Linux it's installed by `sudo yum install mod_security mod_security_crs`. `mod_security` is the module itself, whereas `mod_security_crs` is a bundle of core rules. The blocking of IP-based requests is among them. Others prevent SQL injection and the like.

There comes great responsibility to know which rules are active. You should click through your website with ModSecurity enabled to check whether all user actions are still possible.